# Web service response takes too much time

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6 with Tomcat 6.

I have tested consuming a public Webservice from internet, the response is instant, but when i consume the one from the server the response takes around 5 minutes.

NB: the method that i publish is just a return of string that means the load have nothing to do with developing thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the publishing method.
I used

```
Endpoint.publish("http://192.168.1.103:8080/WS/HelloWorld3",new HelloWorld2Impl());
```

This method response is slow.

The solution was to use the wizard of eclipse of creating WebService publisher.
This wizard will add some files that allows publishing the webservice ounce the server starts.